# diplay title of href and id div in the same line

Tags: css

I want to make title of href and id of div in the same line

this is my code :

```
<a href="#">my link name &nbsp;&nbsp;<div id="iddiv"></div>

</a>
```

so I want to disply :     **my link name  500**

500  is the id of my div

**updated :**

this is my code :

```
<li class="$nav_child.getTitle()">
    <a href="$nav_child.getURL()" class="$nav_child_class" $nav_child.getTarget()>
        $nav_child.getName()&nbsp;&nbsp;<div id="$nav_child.getLayout().getPlid()"></div>
    </a>
</li>
```

for example  using this code it displays :

my link name

500

Comment: You cannot print the id of a div container using only html

Comment: You shouldn't use a div inside an anchor tag

Comment: @franco - Also, you need to work on your 'accept' rate here. You haven't accepted any answers to your questions. People will be less inclined to help if you don't accept.

Comment: @wickywills and why is that? inside `<a>` is [flowcontent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FHTML%2FContent_categories#Flow_content) allowed.

Comment: @rene : My apologies - wasn't aware that was the case with HTML5, thank you. Still hurts me whenever I see it though!

Answer (score 2):

You should use a span instead of the div.

this is one of the differences between span and div.. Div displays text on the next line while span does not.

Answer (score 0):

Make div as "display: inline-block". Your problem will be solved.